# JavaScript execution differences between JavaScript and JavaScript through Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-mobile

I currently have a problem on my javascript code.
I want to create a treeview using this module:

[jqm-tree](http://www.jqueryscript.net/mobile/Dynamic-Tree-View-Plugin-For-jQuery-Mobile-jqm-tree.html)

==Problem==

When I execute the demo code in index.html like this:

```
<script> 
 $("#tree").jqmtree({
    title : 'Items',
    collapsed: true,
    data: [
        { "id": 1, "title": "Menu 1" },
        { "id": 2, "title": "Sub 1 1", "pid":1 },
        { "id": 3, "title": "Sub 1 2", "pid": 1 },
        { "id": 4, "title": "Sub 1 3", "pid": 1 },
        { "id": 5, "title": "Menu 2" },
        { "id": 6, "title": "Sub 2 1", "pid": 5 }
    ]
});
</script>
```

the result is correct.

but when I execute this same demo code after a ajax request like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "data/data.csv",
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(data) 
      {
         $("#tree").jqmtree({
         title : 'Items',
         collapsed: true,
         data: [
             { "id": 1, "title": "Menu 1" },
             { "id": 2, "title": "Sub 1 1", "pid":1 },
             { "id": 3, "title": "Sub 1 2", "pid": 1 },
             { "id": 4, "title": "Sub 1 3", "pid": 1 },
             { "id": 5, "title": "Menu 2" },
             { "id": 6, "title": "Sub 2 1", "pid": 5 }
            ]
        });
      }
 });

});
```

I have not the right result, the collapsible is no longer active on the menu 1 and menu 2. [nok screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiWbj.png)

Can you point me to the reasons for this difference ?

thanks for your help.

==Edit1=

I try to put the demo code without ajax :

```
$(document).on('pagecreate', '#page1' ,function(){
$("#tree").jqmtree({
        title : 'Items',
        collapsed: true,
        data: [
            { "id": 1, "title": "Menu 1" },
            { "id": 2, "title": "Sub 1 1", "pid":1 },
            { "id": 3, "title": "Sub 1 2", "pid": 1 },
            { "id": 4, "title": "Sub 1 3", "pid": 1 },
            { "id": 5, "title": "Menu 2" },
            { "id": 6, "title": "Sub 2 1", "pid": 5 }
        ]
    });



});
```

The result is not good, I don't understand why ;(

Comment: Your sure that ajax fire success?

Comment: Is there supposed to be a script that runs after that call to make it collapsible? It's usually some sort of timing issue when you're working with AJAX requests and things go wrong.

Comment: Are there any errors shown in Console?

Comment: Instead of $(document).ready(function(){... us the jQM pagecreate: $(document).on("pagecreate","#page1", function(){ ...});

Comment: no error in console ;(

Comment: Same problem with $(document).on("pagecreate","#page1", function(){ ...});

Comment: yes, ajax return success